# How do I check for an empty string in a Boolean statement?

Tags: java, string

I have an assignment where I have to attach the letters "un" to any word that the user inputs (unless the inputted word already has "un" in front of it, in which case I just return the inputted word). I'm testing my method but I encountered one problem: my program keeps returning an error if I were to test for an empty input. Here is my code:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);                                              
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    if(input.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("un"))
    {
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    else if(input.equals(""))
    {
        System.out.println("un");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("un" + input);
    }
```

So I wanted to ask how I can test for an empty input/blank string since, evidently, the "" quotations do not work.

Comment: What error are you getting, and where? (Hint: I suspect it's before you get to the second condition...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having this problem because you are trying to get the substring of string that doesnt have the required length. Put the empty string check first.

```
 if(input.equals("")||input.length==1)
    {
       System.out.println("un"); 
    }

    else if(input.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("un"))
    {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("un" + input);
    }
```

Comment: This solution does not work for string with length = 1

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with checking `input.equals("")` per-se. The problem is that you have another test beforehand that throws an exception if `input` is shorter than 2 characters.

There are several ways to solve this, but I'd just simplify things and use [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-). An empty string doesn't really need a special case of its own - just slap `un` before it, and you'll get `un`:

```
if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("un")) {
    System.out.println(input);
} else {
    System.out.println("un" + input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this weren't homework, and the library could be used for other things ( using it in this single purpose may be overkill ), you could use [StringUtils.PrependIfMissing()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#prependIfMissing(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence...)).

It does exactly this and handles nulls as well.

Comment: Changed the link to prepend.